# Drawing multiple plots to one figure frame and zooming with mouse click

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to put multiple plots to one figure windows and when I click one of these it will be open on separate window. Is there any predefined function to do that or what is the trick that makes possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can to this, you need to define a callback-function that does what you want and then set the `axes` property `ButtonDownFcn` equal to this callback.

```
a(1) = subplot(311); // plot stuff
a(2) = subplot(312); // plot stuff
a(3) = subplot(313); // plot stuff
set(a,'ButtonDownFcn', @copyAxesToNewFigure);
```

With regards to creating a new `Figure` that contains a copy of the `axes` you clicked on, a function like this should work:

```
function copyAxesToNewFigure(hObject,eventdata)

  childHandle = get(hObject, 'Children');
  newFig = Figure;
  newAx = Axes;
  copyojb(childHandle, newAx);
```